# See all ambiguous links on a specific Wikipedia page

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Lately, I've been trying to fix ambiguous links on Wikipedia. On one specific Wikipedia page, I want to be able to see every link to a disambiguation page so that I can repair it. Is it possible to do this without clicking on every single link on the page?

Comment: English Wikipedia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [dab solver](http://toolserver.org/~dispenser/view/Dab_solver). Enter the name of the page and it will automatically find the ambiguous links on that page and it will also help you disambiguate them.